# SQL Server - XQuery for XML

Tags: sql, xml, xquery

Just similar other post, I need to retrieve any rows from table applying criteria on Xml column, for instance, supposing you have an xml column like this:

```
<DynamicProfile xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WinTest">
  <AllData xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
    <d2p1:KeyValueOfstringstring>
      <d2p1:Key>One</d2p1:Key>
      <d2p1:Value>1</d2p1:Value>
    </d2p1:KeyValueOfstringstring>
    <d2p1:KeyValueOfstringstring>
      <d2p1:Key>Two</d2p1:Key>
      <d2p1:Value>2</d2p1:Value>
    </d2p1:KeyValueOfstringstring>
  </AllData>
</DynamicProfile>
```

My query would be able to return all rows where node value `<d2p1:Key> = 'some key value'` AND node value `<d2p1Value = 'some value value'`.

Imagine of that just as a dynamic table where KEY node represent the column name and Value node represent column's value.

The following query does not work because key and value nodes are not sequential:

```
select * from MyTable where
MyXmlField.exist('//d2p1:Key[.="One"]') = 1
AND MyXmlField.exist('//d2p1:Value[.="1"]') = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of looking for `//d2p1:key[.="One"]` and `//d2p1:Value[.="1"]` as two separate searches, do a single query that looks for both at once, like so:

`//d2p1:KeyValueOfstringstring[./d2p1:Key="One"][./d2p1:Value=1]`