# We want a query by xmlpath in sql. How can we do this?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Server - XQuery for XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519701/sql-server-xquery-for-xml)

We have a xml column similar to this:

row1:

```
<a f="value1" b="value2" c="value3" d="value4"  />
<a f="value5" b="value6" c="value7" d="value8" Case="value9"  />
```

row2:

```
<a f="value1" b="value15" c="value16" d="value17"  />
<a f="value10" b="value11" c="value12" d="value13" Case="value14"  />
```

...

we want select rows that have `f="value1"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fdfa9/1)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
create table YourTable
(
  XMLColumn xml
)

insert into YourTable values('<a f="value1" b="value2" c="value3" d="value4"  />
<a f="value5" b="value6" c="value7" d="value8" Case="value9"  />')

insert into YourTable values('<a f="value1" b="value15" c="value16" d="value17"  />
<a f="value10" b="value11" c="value12" d="value13" Case="value14"  />')
```

**Query 1**:

```
select *
from YourTable
where XMLColumn.exist('a[@f = "value1"]') = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fdfa9/1/0)**:

```
|                                                                                                              XMLCOLUMN |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|         <a f="value1" b="value2" c="value3" d="value4"/><a f="value5" b="value6" c="value7" d="value8" Case="value9"/> |
| <a f="value1" b="value15" c="value16" d="value17"/><a f="value10" b="value11" c="value12" d="value13" Case="value14"/> |
```